# BinaryReader returning wrong position

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am reading in a file as a stream through a binaryreader. I read in a number of bytes but when checking the basestream position its a lot further a long than it should be.

Code example:

```
public void MainLoader()
{
    FileStream input = System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(input, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
    byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(256); // 256 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadInt32(); //4 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadInt32(); //4 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadInt16(); //2 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadInt32(); //4 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadInt16(); //2 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadBoolean(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadInt16(); //2 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadBoolean(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadInt16(); //2 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadInt16(); //2 bytes
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    binaryReader.ReadByte(); // 1 byte
    // should return 292
    var position = binaryReader.BaseStream.Position
    binaryReader.Close();
}
```

When running this through a winform app it works as expected and the `postion` is 292. When running through a Xamarin.Android app it messes up and comes back as 4096.

I have tried using the default encoding and UTF8 encoding with no change. I am starting to wonder if its down to some `CultureInfo` setting

How can the stream get to this position when the code physically reads in 292 bytes?

Comment: The encoding should be irrelevant as you're never reading any text. My guess is that Mono's `BinaryReader` implementation has a buffer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then this must have changed because it used to work. I have updated Xamarin to the latest release very recently actually.

Comment: It seems that your comment doesn't really relate to mine - if it used to work and it doesn't after an update to Xamarin, then yes, that sounds like it's changed...

Comment: 4096 seems like a typical buffer value. Can you try and check the position an extra time in the middle to see if it is 4096 there as well? Then you know it buffers the read and reports the value incorrectly.

Comment: `new BinaryReader(input, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));`. Very strange that a binary reader needs an encodig.

Comment: @greenapps I read strings in further down and as some users aren't from a Western nation their device might default to a different codepage.

Comment: @jaymarvels `BinaryReader` is based on MS ref. source and has an internal buffer size of at least 16. The underlaying `Stream`, a `FileStream` in this case, has a default buffer size of 4096. If you do not inspect Position, I get 292 on `Xamarin.Android`, but inspecting the object will cause the underlaying stream to populate its buffer to its max size, 4096 if the file being read is more than 4096 bytes in size, otherwise it will equal the file size.

Comment: @SushiHangover you are totally correct. I am sure that in the very near past I was able to inspect without the buffer populating. Though this might have been on a winform app.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using DevExpress Coderush with Debug Visualizer turned on, this automatically inspects the results of code that uses streams, such as BinaryReader which then results in the stream being in the wrong position when the actual line is executed. In my case (also a Xamarin.Android app) I was reading all the bytes from my stream using the binary reader and as soon as I tried to debug around the code the automatic inspection was moving the position and resulting in an "Unable to read beyond the end of the stream" by the time I got further along in the read sequence.

The only way around this for Coderush users is to turn off Debug Visualizer or make sure you don't break and step lines of code which use streams when it is enabled.